# Get height of custom keyboard (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I need to adjust the positioning of several UI elements based on the height of the default keyboard the user has active.  I know how to get the height of the default system keyboard:

```
keyboardHeight = (sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().height
```

However, when I use this code along with a custom keyboard (e.g. SwiftKey), the height returns as 0.  How would I get the height of the custom keyboard?  Sorry if this has already been answered, but I haven't been able to find an answered thread yet... Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`?

Comment: In one of our apps we simply went and disabled all the custom keyboards, mainly for UI purposes

Comment: That's what I did as a temporary fix, thanks!  I'd still be able to like to enable custom keyboards though, it makes for a better user experience IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!  It turns out that the custom keyboard I was testing on my phone (SwiftKey) has THREE keyboardWillShow callbacks for some unknown reason... Bad coding on SwiftKey's/iOS 8's part?  Anyways, I wrote my code in a way that I only used the first callback, but the third callback returned a sender that had the correct info.  In order, `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` on each of the three callbacks returned the height of:

```
No keyboard (0.0)
System's keyboard (also SwiftKey's keyboard without the autocomplete frame above the main keyboard)
Custom keyboard
```

I used the info from the third callback and was able to update my UI elements correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the code here? Does it work for apple keyboard's as well?

Comment: Hi, sorry - unfortunately I don't have access to the code anymore, since I signed a NDA and wasn't able to keep a copy of the app for myself.  I think if you look at the keyboardWillShow callbacks, you'll be able to find what you're looking for.  Have it print each of the callbacks and see what values it returns; you should find the one you're looking for in one of the callbacks.

Comment: Specifically, printing out `keyboardHeight = (sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().height` will probably help you.